# Linq-to-sql speed when getting table count

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq-to-sql

Is this:

```
Dim mydata = (From c In dc.Table Select New With {c.ID}).Count
```

any faster than this:

```
Dim mydata = (From c In dc.Table Select c).Count
```

assuming the table has a good number of fields?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer:  no.

The SQL generated by the LINQ-to-SQL engine should be essentially the same for both forms (if not *exactly* the same) **because you're calling `.Count()` immediately on the query.**

A compiled query version, on the other hand, would be faster after the first execution.  Here's one way to do a compiled query for this:

```
Public Shared FetchCount As Func(Of DataContext, Integer) = _
    CompiledQuery.Compile(Function(context as DataContext) _
        (From c in context.Table Select c).Count())
```

`DataContext` would need to be the Type of the LINQ-to-SQL DBML, and `Table` would need to be the appropriate table.  And, I believe you'll need to import `System.Data.Linq` to have access to `CompiledQuery`.

Comment: @ChrisPhelps - thanks - remember to upvote if you think the answer is good.  It gives us all warm-fuzzy feelings.